# setting opacity 30% to a linear gradient

Tags: css

I've been trying to set a 30% opacity to my `linear-gradient`. I converted my hexidecimal color-codes with rgba color-codes then set 30% so each like I read but that isn't what I am look for I want the whole gradient to be at a 30% opacity over the image I have placed it over. Right now it's just a solid gradient over my image. Plz help!

```
.img-container::after {
      content:"";
      display:block;
      position:absolute;
      top:0;
      bottom:0;
      left:0;
      right:0;
      background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(243,104,25) 30%, rgba(0,0,0) 30%);
    }
```

Comment: the opacity need to be inside the color `rgba` : Red Green Blue Alpha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not specify any alpha value in your rgba definition.

This is essentially a solid color:

```
rgba(243,104,25);
```

This is the same color, but opacity set to 30%:

```
rgba(243,104,25,0.3);
```

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks so much! Didn't realize I needed that to be within the color code.